# React Native can work in sleep mode?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, sleep

I need to work with the timer in my application. All is well until I block the screen. At the time of locking, the application just falls asleep and stops counting the time.

React can work in sleep mode? How can this be realized?

[Example of a timer.](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/pomdo/blob/master/src/store.js)

Comment: If you want to execute code in the background you will need native Android / iOS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try solving your problem in a different way.

I think you can use the AppState of react native (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) to detect if your app goes to inactive/background mode.

At this point you should save to the AsyncStorage the current timestamp. When your app goes back to active state you can then retrieve the saved timestamp and calculate the time passed.

Comment: Can I somehow run the signal after a while?

Comment: The solution I proposed allows you to calculate the time passed when the app becomes active again. If you need to run a specific functionality while the app is inactive then you must follow another approach cause you can't run any code in inactive state in React Native. Maybe if you explain a bit what you want to do here I can help you more.